# Can you help me understand why this boolean method is returning false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean-expression

I have a User model with an account_type attribute that is either "Student" or "Partner". I have created boolean methods in my User model to determine if a user record is either a student or partner (see below).

```
 def student?
    self.account_type == "Student"
  end

  def partner?
    self.account_type == "Partner"
  end
```

In rails console, when I set user equal to an instance of User that has a student account type and enter user.account_type == "Student", I get true but when I call user.student?, I get false. Is there an issue with how I've set up these methods? They seem pretty straight forward so I'm not following why true isn't returned for the record.

Console Output:

```
user = User.last
#<User id: 18, first_name: "gjalrgkj", last_name: "kgjrlgakjrl", email: "terajglrkj@gmail.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$WF.Rw3PzlWilH0X.Nbfxfe5aB18WW6J7Rt4SAKQEwI8...", remember_digest: nil, activation_digest: "$2a$10$/bXG4/nKCiiZHWailUPAmOZj7YhCjKhPm4lUW6nPC3N...", activated: nil, activated_at: nil, reset_digest: nil, reset_sent_at: nil, account_type: "Student", created_at: "2018-07-02 04:21:07", updated_at: "2018-07-02 04:21:07">
>> user.account_type
=> "Student"
>> user.account_type = "Student"
=> "Student"
>> user.student?
=> false
```

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :personal_information

  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :first_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :last_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                      format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
  validates :account_type, presence: true


  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost  BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                              BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  def create_reset_digest   
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_columns(reset_digest: User.digest(reset_token), reset_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
  end

  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    return false if digest.nil?
 BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end


  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end


  def provide_age
    now = Time.now.utc.to_date
    if self.birthday.nil?
      nil
    else
      self.age = now.year - self.birthday.year - ((now.month > self.birthday.month || (now.month == self.birthday.month && now.day >= self.birthday.day)) ? 0 : 1)
      update_attribute(:age, self.age)
    end
  end


  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end  

  def activate
    update_columns(activated: true, activated_at: Time.zone.now)
  end

  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end


  private 

  def downcase_email
    self.email.downcase!
  end

  def create_activation_digest
    self.activation_token  = User.new_token
    self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
  end
end
```

User Helper

```
  def account_type
    [
      ['Student'], 
      ['Partner'], 
      ['School Administrator'], 
      ['Philanthropist']
    ]
  end

  def student?
    self.account_type == "Student"
  end

  def partner?
    self.account_type == "Partner"
  end
 end
```

Comment: can you show the whole model and your console output ?

Comment: Make sure you reload the console to make it got your new code using: `reload!` in rails console

Comment: @Subash - added the model and console - thank you kindly for the assistance.

Comment: That is `User Helper` ? It's account type is an array not a string.

Comment: @Зелёный - Yes, account_type is an array as it is used for a form select field.

Comment: `self` isn't suppose to be a _magic_ variable which refer to the user model everywhere, it's only works with current object. You need to lear some basic stuff about ruby objects and model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 2 methods `student?` and `partner?` belong in the user model.

When you are doing `user.student?` it looks for `student?` method as a instance method in the user model.

`self` in helper is not the user instance it points to your helper module.

Hope this helps.

Comment: glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

try to put this code into your User Model (not in Helper)

```
def student?
  self.account_type == "Student"
end

def partner?
  self.account_type == "Partner"
end
```

and this is a good idea to create a setter to set the account_type, example

```
def set_account_type(type)
  self.account_type = type
end
```

Comment: Account_type is set through the registration form -- there is an account_type select field that uses the account_type method from the User Helper above for the options_for_select container. This works right?